# MySQL counts, from multiple tables, not as I expect

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to get the number of records from 2 different tables `history` and `records`. I have 3 tables in my query, `user`, `history`, and `records`. All 3 tables have one column in common, `userId`.

A `userId` doesn't have to have a record in either the `history` or `records` tables. This is frustrating in that it's a fairly basic query that I can't get to work.

```
select u.userId, count(h.webId) `HistoryCount`, count(r.webId) `PRCount`
from user u
left join history h using(userId)
left join records r using(userId)
group by u.userId;
```

I would expect results like

```
|--------|--------------|---------|
| userid | HistoryCount | PRCount |
|--------|--------------|---------|
|   100  |       1      |    0    |
|   101  |       0      |    1    |
|   102  |       7      |    4    |
|--------|--------------|---------|
```

But I'm seeing results where both the `HistoryCount` and `PRCount` columns have the same values.
I'm seeing results like

```
|--------|--------------|---------|
| userid | HistoryCount | PRCount |
|--------|--------------|---------|
|   100  |       1      |    1    |
|   101  |       1      |    1    |
|   102  |       7      |    7    |
|--------|--------------|---------|
```

Comment: some sample data maybe ?

Comment: Sample `records` data -http://monosnap.com/image/bnRSJWDzOzn5wE5uAQk5VTsp2.png

Sample `history` data -
http://monosnap.com/image/nLrOPCbef5jShWdNOiogdr9kP.png

Comment: please edit your question and add your tables and some sample data , i cant look to this png file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related questions win...

It appears that I need to add a `distinct` to each of my `count` columns.

My edited query, returning results I would expect.

```
SELECT u.userId, count(DISTINCT h.webId) `HistoryCount`, count(DISTINCT r.webId) `PRCount`
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN history h USING(userId)
LEFT JOIN records r USING(userId)
GROUP BY u.userId
```